Opel Astra H 2006 Clutch replacement and subsequent questions
The car has done 262 000 km. Sometimes the clutch would shudder on first few clutch releases after startup, but after a few gear changes, no more shuddering.
The clutch plate, friction disc and concentric slave cylinder has been replaced.
Prior to this maintenance work being done, the clutch pedal stroke worked normally, but since new parts installed, attempts of bleeding the hydraulic line, the pressure builds sufficiently to release friction plate and allow gear changes, but the stroke is not as efficient as it was prior.
When the clutch is bled as per suggested method no more air is being released at the bell housing bleed nipple. There was air being released but that has stopped after numerous cycles of bleeding procedure.
I understand that should any air be present in the hydraulic line, this would lead to the less efficient pedal stroke, with the clutch feeling a but spongy and taking up pressure a little lower than prior to work being done.
I also understand that a failing clutch master cylinder may also be responsible for the lower pressure being built up, this may need to be replaced to resolve or more air somehow bled to improve the operation back to the way prior to work done.
When attempting "the gearchange linkage/mechanism adjustment section 7A●3 as per Hynes Owners Workshop manual Vauxhall/Opel May 2004 - 2008 the gear lever selector shaft pulled out of the transmission linkage rod clamp.
The gear lever has been locked into neutral position to the left side with a 5mm drill bit as per procedure step 8 see photo for details.
The Transmission has also being locked in "3rd gear position" by pressing the spring loaded locking pin on the top of transmission as per procedure step 9 as per photo.
I have no idea why having these two locked in position leads to the gear selector shaft into the engine bay being to short to enter into the rod clamp.
How can the "the gearchange linkage/mechanism adjustment section 7A●3 as per Hynes Owners Workshop manual Vauxhall/Opel May 2004 - 2008 lead to this situation?
Any advice?
[



Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Thanks, hope my explanation and issues are described clearly. South African version of Opel Astra H 2006. Engine number Z16XEP, known as an A04 and L48 model. 77kw motor
